# What's a word or expression for an answer that elicits its own question(s)?

Tags: expressions

I'm trying to think of a way of referring to the sort of half-ass answers you might find in response to the question: **"why do we sleep at night?"** Typical answers such as **"we need to sleep so that our body can repair"** or **"we sleep to conserve energy"** are really non-answers in the sense that they immediately elicit their own question(s) (namely, **"*why* does our body need sleep in order to repair itself?"** and **"*why* do we need to conserve energy?"**)

Is there some word or clever turn of phrase used to refer to such answers?

Comment: You could say it's an "unhelpful answer" if it does not clarify the topic or, if the answer is only expressing the same content as the question with different words, "a circular answer" or else a "tautology"

Comment: @JoBedard This is getting close but I don't think it's quite a circular answer/argument/reasoning or a tautology. More like a red herring in that it is distracting from the original question by creating new questions, but it's not really that either.

Answer (score 1):

The possible description are

- Perpetual or Infinite Regress
- Recursion

The behaviour closest to your description is Perpetual or Infinite Regress.

> An [infinite regress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_regress) in a series of propositions arises if the truth of proposition P1 requires the support of proposition P2, the truth of proposition P2 requires the support of proposition P3, ... , and the truth of proposition Pn-1 requires the support of proposition Pn and n approaches infinity.

*Regression* generally means to go back to a previous state, or to reverse to the origin of the current state. Therefore, regression also means to relapse to a previous condition.

Regressed resolution is finding the cause of the problem.

We could call such never-ending regressive questioning

- perpetuated regressed inquisition
- recursive black-hole of regressive resolution
- bottomless pit of regressive inquisition
- never-ending regressive story of life
- regressive life of pi (because pi being the factor of a circle, and whose value is infinitely regressively discovered.)
- till the pi comes home

We could invent a couple of new idioms like,

- I am being questioned *till the pi comes home*.
- Her incessant questioning subjected me to the effects of the regressive life of pi.
- I am being annoyed by *perpetually regressed inquisitions*.

A lot of people have trouble comprehending past participles, so that we would have to express *perpetuated regressed inquisition* as a less precise phrase *perpetually regressive inquisition*.

#### Glossary

> [Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) is the process of repeating items in a self-similar way. Recursion is the process a procedure goes through when one of the steps of the procedure involves invoking the procedure itself. A procedure that goes through recursion is said to be *recursive*.

> [recursion](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/recursion) (rɪˈkɜːʃən)
>   n
>
> 1. the act or process of returning or running back
> 2. (Logic) logic maths the application of a function to its own values to generate an infinite sequence of values. The recursion formula or clause of a definition specifies the progression from one term to the next, as given the base clause f(0) = 0, f(n + 1) = f(n) + 3 specifies the successive terms of the sequence f(n) = 3n
> 3. (Mathematics) logic maths the application of a function to its own values to generate an infinite sequence of values. The recursion formula or clause of a definition specifies the progression from one term to the next, as given the base clause f(0) = 0, f(n + 1) = f(n) + 3 specifies the successive terms of the sequence f(n) = 3n
>      [C17: from Latin recursio, from recurrererecur]
>
> reˈcursive adj

Comment: nice answer. This is certainly the most accurate on a technical level... I only wish it wasn't so mathematical. I don't think anyone without a math major would know what I'm talking about if I said "infinite regress" or "perpetually regressed inquisitions"! But unless a better answer comes along in the next little while I'll accept this.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably nothing you can do, because a man can make a question on **every line** (in whatsoever sense) you say.

But, you may send the conversation in an endless loop, for example if you interpret the question by laying emphasis on **'at night'**, then you may answer 'It is because we don't sleep in the day'. And, the resulting question would be that 'Why we don't sleep in the day?'. So, you may answer 'Because, we sleep at night'.

Comment: lol this is true but I'm not looking to get into a philosophical discussion, I just want a synonym!

Comment: To be fair, a woman can turn every line of everything you say into a question, too. That's not a male prerogative.

Answer (score 0):

> 'Giving a C- answer to an A+ question'

indicates that the answer is not totally without value, but is barely satisfactory.

Perhaps one could see C- and half-assed as synonyms.

Comment: ok nice this is more along the lines of what I was looking for. Ideally something more succinct though. There ought to be a technical term for this... something impressive sounding like "non sequitur" would do nicely :P